# Displaying dynamically created image on my ASP.NET WebForm

Tags: asp.net

On my Form Load event I am creating a bitmap using System.Drawing classes, and I want to display this image on my WebForm.  How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: I have no clue where to start.

Comment: How about posting the code you have which creates the bitmap. Add a comment for 'magic goes here' so we know where to help. Also, are you using c# or vb?

Comment: The bitmap is successfully created.  I simply need to know how to display it on my form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create this bitmap directly in your webform. You will need to implement custom `HttpHandler` that will render this image separately.

- [Serving Dynamic Content with HTTP Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972953.aspx)
- [HTTP Handlers for Images in ASP.NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/desaijm/HTTPHandlersForImages11152005062705AM/HTTPHandlersForImages.aspx)
- [Use Custom HTTP Handlers in Your ASP.NET Applications](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3565541/Use-Custom-HTTP-Handlers-in-Your-ASPNET-Applications.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the image in the code behind for your page, what you should do is create a URL for the image that somehow describes or defines the image's content (perhaps along with session state or a cookie if you need to), and attach that URL to a regular `<img>` (or `<asp:Image>`) tag.

Then, when the browser requests that URL, your code determines the parameters from the query string or cookies or whatever, generates and sends the response, and returns it with the correct MIME type. That's usually best done from a Generic HttpHandler (*.ashx).